# Visual Basic Outlook Run Perl Script

Tags: vba, perl, outlook

I am trying to use visual basic in outlook to run a script which runs a perl script in the specified folder

```
Sub run_python()
    Shell ("perl C:\Users\lachlann\Desktop\test.pl")
End Sub
```

this is the perl script

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'log.txt';
open(my $fh, '>', $filename) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
print $fh "My first report generated by perl\n";
close $fh;
```

however when i run the visual basic macro there is no text written in the file log.txt

Comment: `'log.txt'` is relative. Are you sure you're looking in the proper place for the file? Have you checked whether the script is being executed at all? Why are you calling `run_python()` on a Perl script? My guess is that if things are executing properly, you're not checking the correct file for the information. Try printing to STDOUT instead... in the Perl script: `print "hello, world!\n";` You do not show where `run_python()` is called. Are you sure you're calling it?

Comment: ++ for `use warnings; use strict;` and 3-arg open with a check, btw.

Comment: May be use *Use Shell + Explorer.exe* `Shell "Explorer.exe ""C:\Users\lachlann\Desktop\test.pl""", 1` see if that works